# How to get if statement to print a value inside array

Tags: python

In this example, I am trying to make it so that if variable == one of the values in the array, it prints "This Works".

```
array = [1, 2]

one = 1
two = 2

def trying():
    if one == array:
        print("This Works")

print(trying())
```

I understand that one and array isn't the same, but how do I go about getting one and the value 1 to equal, so that this code works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `in` instead of `==`,

```
array = [1, 2]

one = 1
two = 2

def trying():
    if one in array:
        print("This Works")

print(trying())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from array import array

array = array('i', [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
one = array[0]
two = array[1]

def get_if_statement(array, one, two):
    if array[0] == 1:
        print(array[0])
    elif array[1] == 2:
        print(array[1])
    else:
        print("None")
```